# Sorting a 3D matrix by only the first row MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

I am having trouble sorting a 3D matrix by whichever row I want, but still having the other two columns match up with the one sorted row.

ex)before sort:

```
    5 4 1 
    4 6 3
    9 6 5
```

after sort:

```
    1 4 5
    3 6 4
    5 6 9
```

So only the first row got sorted in ascending order, the other two rows simply stayed in their respective columns.

I have tried sort(Matrix(1,:,:)), but this seems to sort all three rows.I'm guessing there is some matlab function that can do this, but I haven't found anything. Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, what you have here is a 2D matrix.

Comment: My mistake, I am dealing with a color image with dimention 100x100x3. 3 representing red green and blue. Same issue though

Comment: Ok then my answer below should help you. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use output arguments with `sort` to reorder the matrix as you want with indexing.

Example:

```
clear
clc

a = [5     4     1
     4     6     3
     9     6     5]

 %// Select row of interest
 row = 1;

 [values,indices] = sort(a(row,:)) %// Since you have a 3D matrix use "a(row,:,:)"

 b = a(:,indices) %// In 3D use "b = a(:,indices,:)"
```

Output:

```
b =

     1     4     5
     3     6     4
     5     6     9
```

Comment: Quick question, in b = a(:, indices, : ) why is indices placed in the middle?

Comment: Because the indices correspond to the columns, which is the 2nd dimension :)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using [`sortrows`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html?refresh=true)

```
%// Input
a = [5     4     1
     4     6     3
     9     6     5]

%// code
sortrows(A.').'           %// for 2D

%// Results:
 1     4     5
 3     6     4
 5     6     9
------------------------------------------------
[t,ind] = sortrows(A(:,:,1).')    %// for 3D
A(:,ind,:)
```

Comment: This would be my approach too

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks.. thats a great compliment to me :)